# Why doesn't the vite-plugin-rewrite-all plugin work in preview mode?

Tags: reactjs, vite

I can't use . (dot) on my React Vite app url. Some suggestions are to use the `vite-plugin-rewrite-all` plugin to work around this. It does work but only in development mode. When I build and run using `npm run preview`, I still can't access pages that contain dots in the url. My example URL is like this :

```
http://localhost:4173/dashboard/users/edit/cpt.america
http://localhost:4173/dashboard/users/edit/john.doe
```

Here's my configuration in `vite.config.mts`:

```
import path from 'path';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import jsconfigPaths from 'vite-jsconfig-paths';
import pluginRewriteAll from 'vite-plugin-rewrite-all';

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), pluginRewriteAll(), jsconfigPaths()],
  base: process.env.VITE_APP_BASE_NAME,
  define: {
    global: 'window'
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      {
        find: /^~(.+)/,
        replacement: path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules/$1')
      },
      {
        find: /^src(.+)/,
        replacement: path.join(process.cwd(), 'src/$1')
      }
    ]
  },
  server: {
    open: true,
    port: 4173
  },
  preview: {
    open: true,
    port: 4173
  },
  build: {
    outDir: 'myAPP',
  }
});
```

Is there any additional configuration so that vite-plugin-rewrite-all also runs in preview mode? I'm using Vite v4.5.0

Answer (score 0):

Vite uses seperate configurations for `dev` & `preview` servers. According to the docs `configureServer` function is used to customize `dev` server ([link](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin.html#configureserver)) and `configurePreviewServer` has to be used if you need to customize `preview` server ([link](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin.html#configurepreviewserver)).

If we look inside of `vite-plugin-rewrite-all` [sources](https://github.com/ivesia/vite-plugin-rewrite-all/blob/master/src/index.ts), we'll notice that it uses only `configureServer`. The plugin is very small, so you can simply copy its sources to your project and use both `configureServer` & `configurePreviewServer` function.

Comment: I followed exactly as you said but it doesn't work in preview mode either. Even with my custom plugin the page keeps showing `Cannot GET /dashboard/users/edit/cpt.america` in preview mode. I copied the code from `vite-plugin-rewrite-all`

Comment: I can look at it if you provide a repository where I can reproduce the issue and test the solution.